# XMLWriter using with loop in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

i want to create multiple XML file by using php. i used following code which is working fine for single XML file generation but when i try to same code in loop for generation multiple XML file with different name its throw an error but file is save in destination driver can anyone help me to solve this issue

```
$fileName   =   date('YmdHis').rand('0000','999999')."output.xml";
```

working fine for single calling

```
xmlGenerater($pimcoArr ,$fileName);
```

error throw when i call it in loop

```
for($=0;$i<2;$i++){
 xmlGenerater($pimcoArr ,$fileName);
}
```

error message screen

[image]

XML file genartion method

```
function xmlGenerater($data ,$fileName){

    if(!empty($data)){

        $writer = new XMLWriter();
        //lets store our XML into the memory so we can output it later
        $writer->openMemory();
        //lets also set the indent so its a very clean and formatted XML
        $writer->setIndent(true);
        //now we need to define our Indent string,which is basically how many blank spaces we want to have for the indent
        $writer->setIndentString("    ");
        //Lets start our document,setting the version of the XML and also the encoding we gonna use
        //XMLWriter->startDocument($string version, $string encoding);
        $writer->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
        //lets start our main element,lets call it “ersvpresponse”
        $writer->startElement('ersvpresponse');



        $loop = 1;
        foreach($data as $dataRow){

            $pimco_id       = $dataRow['pimco_id'];
            $event_id       = $dataRow['event_id'];
            $contact_id     = $dataRow['contact_id'];
            $status         = $dataRow['status'];

            $writer->startElement("contact");
            if($loop==1){
                $dateTime   =   date('Y-m-d');
                $writer->writeAttribute("updated",$dateTime); 
            }
            //now we create  pimcoeventid node
            $writer->startElement("pimcoeventid");
            $writer->text("$pimco_id"); 
            $writer->endElement();

            //now we create  pimcocontactid node
            $writer->startElement("pimcocontactid");
            $writer->text("$contact_id"); 
            $writer->endElement();

            //now we create  pimcocontactid node
            $writer->startElement("ersvpstatus");
            $writer->text("$status"); 
            $writer->endElement();

            $writer->endElement();

            $loop++;
        }

        //Now lets close our main element
        $writer->endElement();
        //close our document
        $writer->endDocument();



        /*Lets output what we have so far,first we need to set a header so we can display the XML in the
        browser,otherwise you will need to look at the source output. */

        header('Content-type: text/xml');

        //lets then echo our XML;

        //echo $writer->outputMemory();
        /* that is enough to display our dynamic XML in the browser,now if you wanna create a XML file we need to do this */
        $filename = "exportFiles/$fileName";
        //lets output the memory to our file variable,and we gonna put that variable inside the file we gonna create
        $file = $writer->outputMemory();
        //lets create our file
        file_put_contents($filename,$file);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the documents in separate files on the server but you send them to the client as one single repsonse document, hence the

```
Line Number 14
<?xml ...
```

and that doesn't work, you can't just concatenate xml documents and expect the client-side parser to accept that.
But you could e.g. zip those files and send the archive.

Comment: no i don't concatenate xml element i created new file each $fileName will be dynamic, can you please point out where i did this mistake?

Comment: All I see is that the client-side parser detects an xml declaration (the `<?xml ...>` thingy) on line 14 in the document it parses and it says `junk after document element` which indicates that it was able to parse the (first) document but then found another, concatenated one. Each time you call xmlGenerater() the xml document is stored in a file on the server _and_ the contents is sent to the client via `echo $file;`. You call xmlGenerater() more than once, hence more than one xml document is sent to the client within a single response document.

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue ? because i need to create multiple XML file with different data & different file name

Comment: One possible solution: Let xmlGenerater() return $filename instead of sending the contents via echo. Store that filename in an array. Create a zip archive of the xml documents using that filename array. Send the zip archive to the client/browser.

Comment: i follow your instruction but nothing change

Comment: @ the end of function
return $filename; & get into array like this $fileNameArr[] = xmlGenerater($eventDataRow , $fileName);

Comment: Problem is solve there is also header('Content-type: text/xml'); which need to be move from "xmlGenerater()"